# .net Compact Framework with Windows mobile

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I am confused about .net Compact Framework for windows Mobile and .net Compact framework for windows CE. Are they different OS? I am looking for some questions on .net CF.
I read this question online and looking for a right answer - What is missing from the .NET Compact Framework which is in the full .NET framework? (Shows that they're not just a .NET developer blagging it). What would you do when you need to use something that's not included? I know what is missing in .net CF that is in full .net Framework but what do we do other than googling for something that is not in .net CF?

Any ideas please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always start with the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273) articles.

The compact frameworks are the same for both OS platforms you simply target the correct operating system while deploying. There are some differences within the operating systems such as the State and Notification broker on Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, the Compact Framework leave out **development simplifying tools** (or redundant features, if you don't mind) of the full versions.

Typically, there will exist a core functions that still allow a developer to perform the same tasks. It is like they removed all of the "makes it easy" wrappers.

For example: Say you wanted to know if the word "Christ" was in the word "Christmas".

In the full version, you could write:

```
public bool Contains(string source, string item) {
  return source.Contains(item);
}
```

See how nice and easy that was?

You can still perform this action under the Compact Framework, but this time you're going to have to do more low level analyzing:

```
public bool Contains(string source, string item) {
  return (-1 < source.IndexOf(item));
}
```

See? It is still possible, you just have to use a more limited subset of tools.

Comment: The work redundant is a little misleading. Take the subset of WCF, I would not consider it redundant to not include the TCP/IP and only the HTTP stack.

Comment: Is **development simplifying tools** better?